# Is file_get_contents in PHP the same as toDataUrl in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to use an API to compress images. It says the input can as well be a buffer (string with binary), for example:

```
$sourceData = file_get_contents("unoptimized.jpg");
$resultData = \Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)->toBuffer();
```

In my understanding, they use `file_get_contents` to create that buffer from a file.

In my case, I already got an canvas image using a React application. To make the API call, I create a data URI, using `.toDataURL()` looking something like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh... // lots of letters
```

So can I just use this data URI instead of `file_get_contents`, because both commands actually do the same in different languages, or is there a difference? Like:

```
$sourceData = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...'
\Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)->toBuffer();
```

API Reference: https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file_get_contents` returns the content of a file as string, and that string exactly represents the content of the file.

`.toDataURL()` gives you a data url. The `data:image/png;base64,` part tells that the following data represents a *png* and that the data is *base64* encoded.

To get the same data representation as you get with `file_get_content` you would need to decode the `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...`

So yes, both give you the content of a file, but they don't do that in the same way.

To `toBlob` on the other hand will return a Buffer containing the data in the *same* representation as `file_get_contents` would do.

Comment: If [`fopen wrappers`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are enabled, the wrapper takes care of decoding.

Comment: @axiac that's true. I don't know the _Tinify_ library, but `\Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)`  does not look like it would use `fopen` internally (especially because `fromFile` and `fromUrl` exists), but instead would assume that it is a buffer holding the data. But even if they would do, then the point is still valid, `toDataURL` and `file_get_contents` do not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a PNG file named `input.png`, the following two pieces of code produce the same result:

1. Read the image data from the PNG file:

   ```
   $sourceData = file_get_contents('input.png');
   ```
2. Read the image data from a `data:` URL generated from the PNG file:

   ```
   // Generate the 'data:' URL
   $url = 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents('input.png'));

   // Read the image data from the 'data:' URL
   $sourceData = file_get_contents($url);
   ```

The second piece of code works only if [fopen wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) are enabled on the server where the `file_get_contents()` is executed.

It doesn't make much sense to use the second fragment of code in a single script (because it does a redundant encoding and decoding) but it makes a lot of sense if the encoding and restoring (decoding) happen in different scripts.

They can be part of the same application (the script that encodes the data stores it in the database, the other script loads from the database, restores the image data and uses it) or the decoding could happen in a remote application that sends the data URL over the Internet to be decoded and used by a different application.