# How to convert data URI to buffer (string with binary)?

Tags: php

I am using react to edit an image and send its final data using `mycanvas.toDataURL()` to php.

The [API I am using](https://tinypng.com/developers/reference/php) says, instead of an image, I could although

> [...] upload an image from a buffer (a string with binary)

Their example looks like this:

```
$sourceData = file_get_contents("example.jpg");
$resultData = \Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)->toBuffer();
```

Like I said, instead of an uploaded image, I have got a data URI looking like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABDgAAAQ4C2dj892d2dh98a2d...
```

How can I convert this data URI to a valid buffer to be used as `$sourceData`?

Comment: How is this question different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49628136/4265352) you asked two hours ago?

Comment: The question before was about the difference of file_get_contents and toDataURL. I have tried to adopt both of your solutions to work for me, but I was not able to. Instead of differing from the threads question and continue asking for "how to"s, I thought its a better approach to open a new thread for it, with the specific goal in mind.

Comment: My answer to your other question points out an important fact: if it succeeds, `file_get_contents('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA...')` produces the data you need. If it doesn't work then all you need from the accepted answer to this question is the `explode()` and `base64_decode()` calls. The rest is garbage (regarding to your question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try converting the string to an image file and then send that file, you can use a code like this to do that:

```
function base64_to_image($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 

    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );

    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );

    fclose( $ifp ); 

    return $output_file; 
}
```

So, just call it like :

```
$file = base64_to_image('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...', 'myImage.png');
$sourceData = file_get_contents($file);
$resultData = \Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)->toBuffer();
```

**Edit:** 
Alternatively(preferred) you can just use the decoded string as is instead of writing to a file and reading it. Like this:

```
function base64_to_image($base64_string) {    
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
    return base64_decode($data[ 1 ]);
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
$sourceData = base64_to_image('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...');
$resultData = \Tinify\fromBuffer($sourceData)->toBuffer();
```